# How to convert Nnumpy array to a dictionary in Python?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, dictionary

Hi guys how would I go on converting numpy arrays as such:

```
[[  8.82847075  -5.70925653]
 [  1.07032615  -1.77975378]
 [-10.41163742  -0.33042086]
 [  0.23799394   5.5978591 ]
 [  7.7386861   -4.16523845]]
```

To what I desire in Python 3.10. That includes having the keys and values rounded to the nearest integer:

```
{'9':-6, '1':-2, '-10':0, '0':6, '8':-4}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work

```
a = np.round(a)
d = dict(zip(a[:, 0].astype(str), a[:, 1]))
```

Note: Equal keys will merge.

Comment: What do you mean by "Equal keys will merge"? Isn't that a characteristic of dictionaries where all the keys have to be unique or am I getting this wrong?

Comment: Yes! I mean, if a key appears twice, then the latter one will replace the former. For example, if a=[[1, 2], [1, 3]], then d={'1':3}.

Answer (score 1):

```
dict(zip(*d.round().astype(int).T))
Out: {9: -6, 1: -2, -10: 0, 0: 6, 8: -4}
```

---

The data

```
d = np.array([[  8.82847075,  -5.70925653],
       [  1.07032615,  -1.77975378],
       [-10.41163742,  -0.33042086],
       [  0.23799394,   5.5978591 ],
       [  7.7386861 ,  -4.16523845]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert array to dictionary without any external library.
this method uses list comprehension:

assuming input array is in_array and the output dictionary is out_dict

```
out_dict = {int(x[0]):int(x[1]) for x in in_array}
```